# How to deploy an artifact from repository to AppEngine

Tags: cloudbees

I would like to create a Jenkins that deploys an artifact that already exists in my Maven repository to Google AppEngine.

Currently I have a job that both builds and deploys, but I would like to split this into two separate jobs:

- One job that builds an artifact and deploys it to the repository
- A second job that takes the artifact from the repository and deploys it to AppEngine

The AppEngine deploy task expects the project to be available in the workspace, so I suppose I would need to create a task that downloads and extract the artifact, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is to use the copy-artifact plugin to copy built artifact from another job.
Another, probably better option is for you to setup in your build job a [promotion](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) to deploy to AppEngine, so you have a distinct deployment process (artifact won't be deployed on every build) but no need for complex job setup.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going for the first option. I've already set up a promotion to deploy to the test environment, but I don't want to do that for my production deploy. For now I want to trigger that manually.